Clearing the exim mail queue using PHP (CentOS v7.9)
I'm trying to clear the exim mail queue using my php script on CentOS v7.9.
I can easily get the mail queue count by issuing the following php command without any problems:
shell_execute("echo *root password* | sudo -S /usr/sbin/exim -bpc");

However, when i try to clear the mail queue using the following command, i get "no message id given after -Mrm option":
shell_execute("echo *root password* | sudo -S /usr/sbin/exiqgrep/exiqgrep -z -i | xargs /usr/sbin/exim -Mrm 2>&1");

Even when I try to execute the following command i get the same error message "no message id given after -Mrm option":
shell_execute('echo *root password* | sudo -S /usr/sbin/exim -bp|grep "<"|awk {\'print $3\'}|xargs /usr/sbin/exim -Mrm 2>&1');

I can run the same above commands without any problems using the Terminal in WHM without the echo root password sudo part. The problem happens when I try to run these commands using a php script.
Any help will be appreciated
